# Definition of homeomorphic?

Tags: functions, definition

I am looking up the definition of "homeomorphic" and the source I am looking at says there are two different definitions:

> 1. Possessing similarity of form,
> 2. Continuous, one-to-one, in surjection, and having a continuous inverse.

2. seems to be speaking of a particular function/mapping, so I'm okay with that. But "possessing similarity of form" is not rigorous so I don't understand what is meant by that. Does it just mean there exists a function that is continuous, one-to-one, in surjection, and has a continuous inverse from one set to another? Like when it is said that e.g. "the $2$-sphere is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$," does that mean there exists no function $f: S^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $f$ is continuous, one-to-one, in surjection, and has a continuous inverse?

Comment: Which source are you looking at?

Comment: @Neal http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Homeomorphic.html

Comment: Note that 1. is in fact the literal translation of *homeo* (ὅμοιος - equal, similar) *morph* (μορφή - form, shape) *ic*

Comment: Definition 1) I most often see pertains to a "homomorphic", in that it preserves structure. A homeomorphism is really like the topological, analogous definition for a homomorphism.

Comment: I have found MathWorld to frequently be unhelpful or unreliable for things related to topology.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two topological spaces are *homeomorphic* iff there exists a mapping as described in (2) between them, a continuous 1-1 map $f$ from one onto the other space whose inverse $f^{-1}$ is also continuous.  Because of this condition, both $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are called *homeomorphisms*, i.e. maps that *preserve* the underlying topological structure of a space.

Thus the two topological spaces have the same topological structure.  This gives a rigorous interpretation to (1); as the OP points out, without more context statement (1) about "similarity of form" lacks rigor.

The example of two spaces, the 2-sphere $S^2$ and the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$, that are *not* homeomorphic illustrates the topic.  If these were homeomorphic spaces, their topological properties (preserved under homeomorphism) would be the same.  But compactness is a topological property (preserved indeed by continuous surjections), and $S^2$ is compact but $\mathbb{R}^2$ is not compact.  So we know these spaces are not homeomorphic.

Answer (score 9):

The source is likely referring to the English word "homeomorphic" and has nothing to do with mathematics.  Notice how closely the definitions map to dictionary.com's [homeomorphism](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/homeomorphism?s=t):

> noun
>
> 1. similarity in crystalline form but not necessarily in chemical
>      composition.
> 2. *Mathematics*. a function between two topological spaces that is
>      continuous, one-to-one, and onto, and the inverse of which is
>      continuous.

From the etymology it seems that the chemical term "homeomorphous" dates back to 1832, so that usage effectively predates the field of topology itself (not counting the ever-prescient Euler).

Comment: It's an especially poor specimen of Wolfram's MathWorld because the following paragraph tries to explain homeomorphism in terms of *deformation*, a related but distinct concept in topology.

Comment: @hardmath Oi!  I checked archive.org, it seems that MathWorld has had this same definition for over 10 years.  I think this makes me less critical of Wikipedia's occasional big gaffes :).

Answer (score 2):

The first definition is bizarre and is not at all standard mathematical terminology.  Maybe "homeomorphic" can be used with that informal meaning in a non-mathematical context (though I haven't found any such usage by googling; the only other usage I can find is a different technical meaning in chemistry).  In short, don't worry about that supposed first definition; you will never see anyone using it.

Comment: It's not bizarre, it's just not the mathematical meaning of the word. A lot of math words have meanings outside mathematics, like isomorphic, homology, etc. These often pre-date the mathematical terms, and are motivations for the reason they were chosen by mathematicians. You might find something  surprising, but "bizarre" is a judgement.

Comment: It's bizarre because it's on MathWorld, a site specifically about mathematics. If you look up a term like "union" on MathWorld you would not expect to find a discussion of its ordinary English usage in addition to its technical mathematical meaning. I'm also not convinced that the non-mathematical usage actually exists; every dictionary I've found online mentions the mathematical usage and/or the chemistry usage, but no generic "similar form" usage.